# How to get crash information of an executable to another dependent executable?

Tags: linux, c++

I have two C++ compiled executables in Linux machine, both are dependent on each other. First task has to monitor the second task continuously and if second task either terminates or restarts, the first binary has to receive the feedback.

so far both tasks have start using `systemctl` By make second task as part of first task in unit file.

```
# first.service file   
[Unit]
    Description=xx
    PartOf=second.service
    Wants=second.service
```

it makes first task restart if second task restart/stopped.
but first executable has to receive the feedback after or before the second task crash.
Kindly suggest me a solution to perform this using C++.

Comment: uh, that actually sounds more involved! What are these two things, that they mutually watch each other? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a separate watchdog service, which does nothing but watching your two tasks, and is very robust? (that would be the industry standard solution: Make your monitoring infrastructure robust and redundant, and keep it separate from the "payload" services, to keep it robust.)

Comment: does linux have any watchdog service for executables?

Comment: It does, you're already using it! Systemd has such abilities.

Comment: for simulating crash on second task i have performed divide by 0 , but there is no action happening in first task and second task simply closed, is there is any specific configuration in Systemd would give feedback to first task?

Comment: No, honestly, that sounds like a strange design approach.